# When a new firebird data connection, inactive the OK button, in C# Window application

Tags: c#, firebird-embedded

The following are installed:
 - Visual Studio Community 2015
 - DDEX from Firebird SQL website
 - to Solution from NuGet: EntityFramework v6.1.3, EntityFramework.Firebird v4.10.0, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient v4.10.0 (Firebord ADO.Net Data Provider)

New Firebird data connection is created, the OK button is inactive.

I choose my Data Model in Solution Explorer. Right-mouse click -> Genrate Database from Model -> Click on the New Connection button in Generate Database Wizard window -> Select the Firebird Data Source from the data source list (Data Provider: .NET Framework Data Provier for Firebird) -> Click on the Continue button -> and inactive the OK button on Connection Properties window, Test Connection successfully.

**App.config file:**

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird"/>
</providers>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

[image: Connection Properties window in Visual Studio Community 2015]

Can somebody help me?

Sorry, my bad English language.

Comment: You forgot the enter a host name under "Data Source".

Comment: Thanks, Mark. It is work fine.